# fabricjs IText missing stroke after using toSVG

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

There seems to be a bug in fabricjs when using toSVG together with IText. 
When changing an IText which has a stroke, then fabricjs breaks all the characters into seperate tspans with stroke-width = 0.

As shown in this example (Try editing the text twice by adding new letters):

https://jsfiddle.net/xx37jpms/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text_input = new fabric.IText("Edit this and save", {           
    fontSize: 100,
    stroke: '#dd5f60',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: '#00ff00',
});

canvas.add(text_input);
canvas.renderAll();
document.getElementById('svg').innerHTML = canvas.toSVG();

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('svg').innerHTML = canvas.toSVG();
}
```

As can be seen, the SVG code before editing is:

```
        <text font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="100" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 2; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
            <tspan x="-354.09" y="31.5" fill="#00ff00">Edit this and save</tspan>
        </text>
```

But after it becomes:

```
         <text font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="100" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 2; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">
            <tspan x="-295.75" y="31.5" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">E</tspan>
            <tspan x="-234.66" y="31.5" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">d</tspan>
            <tspan x="-184.66" y="31.5" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">i</tspan>
            <tspan x="-156.88" y="31.5" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">t</tspan>
            <tspan x="-129.1" y="31.5" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;"> </tspan>
            <tspan x="-104.1" y="31.5" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">l</tspan>
            <tspan x="-76.33" y="31.5" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;"> </tspan>
            <tspan x="-51.33" y="31.5" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">a</tspan>
            <tspan x="-6.94" y="31.5" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">n</tspan>
            <tspan x="43.06" y="31.5" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">d</tspan>
            <tspan x="93.06" y="31.5" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;"> </tspan>
            <tspan x="118.06" y="31.5" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">s</tspan>
            <tspan x="156.97" y="31.5" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">a</tspan>
            <tspan x="201.36" y="31.5" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">v</tspan>
            <tspan x="251.36" y="31.5" style="stroke: rgb(221,95,96); stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,255,0); fill-rule: ; opacity: 1;">e</tspan>
        </text>
```

This is a big problem for us, but I have no idea how to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't reproduce your scenario.

Comment: I Inferon, thank you for you comment. If you could try editing the text twice, by adding new letters. It happens for me on all browsers and systems.

Comment: The bug happens for me. Wouldn't it be better to ask the FabricJS guys about this bug?

Comment: Yeah, but they are very busy, so was hoping someone knew of a fix until an official fix was released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [reviver](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toSVG) function to modify the output SVG markup. In your case you can use it to remove `stroke-width: 0`:

```
function reviver(markup) {
  return markup.replace(/stroke-width: 0;/g, "");
}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('svg').innerHTML = canvas.toSVG({}, reviver);
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/s35fxaby/